# Multiple Systems of Equations in one line

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, align

I have three small systems of equations, with two equations each. I want to display them like in the following picture:

[image]

The first equations should be in one line and the second equations should be in one line as well and should be aligned to the first equations.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        3x+4y &=14 \qquad 3x+4y &=14 \qquad 3x+4y &=14 \\
       -5x+2y &=20 \qquad -6x-8y &=14 \qquad -6x-8y &=-28
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

But this code produces the following:

[image]

I get no compiling errors, but the second equation is still not aligned, how can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps an `align*` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        3x+4y &=14 &  3x+4y &=14 &  3x+4y &=14 \\
       -5x+2y &=20 & -6x-8y &=14 & -6x-8y &=-28
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @BlackMild, thanks for the edit!!

Comment: @JuanCastaño I just add the output of your code (and save for later use). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array` to format a set of equations

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength\arraycolsep{\dimexpr3em/18}
  \begin{array}{
    rcr @{{}={}} l
    @{\hspace{3em}}
    rcr @{{}={}} l
    @{\hspace{3em}}
    rcr @{{}={}} l
    }
     3x &+& 4y & 14   &    3x &+& 4y & 14   &    3x &+& 4y &  14 \\
    -5x &+& 2y & 20   &   -6x &-& 8y & 14   &   -6x &-& 8y & -28
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Np. I just posted an alternative approach in case you would consider further alignment with coefficients; array is particularly useful if you happen to need centred alignments.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to input linear systems is with the `systeme` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\systeme{3x+4y=14,-5x+2y=20}
\qquad
\systeme{3x+4y=14,-6x-8y=14}
\qquad
\systeme{3x+4y=14,-6x-8y=-28}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sysdelim..
\systeme{3x+4y=14,-5x+2y=20}
\qquad
\systeme{3x+4y=14,-6x-8y=14}
\qquad
\systeme{3x+4y=14,-6x-8y=-28}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

By default a brace is used on the left, corresponding to

```
\sysdelim\lbrace.
```

(the period denotes the null delimiter). In the second example, also the left delimiter is null.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know about this package.

Answer (score 0):

I agree of course with @Juancastaño answer.

However  there is no need to switch from `equation`/`aligned` to `align`!
The key point is that, in both environments,  successive equations on   the same line must be separated by a `&` which delimits the RHS of equation *n*, to be aligned left, from the LHS of equation *n*+1, to be aligned right.
This also ensure that there is no need to add spacing commands like `\qquad`(removed by Juan), as `amsmath` alignmemt environments spread the available white space to maximize the distance between the above referenced RHS and LHS.